# Procedure or function 'usp_StoredProcName' expects parameter '@inputVal', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cmd

I am using a code to call a Stored Procedure having 2 output and 1 input parameter. But i keep getting an error every time I call this stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_StoredProcName]
@inputVal nvarchar(255),
@isError bit OUTPUT,
@errorInfo nvarchar(255) OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @totalRow int = 0;
DECLARE @inputValID uniqueidentifier;

SET @isError = 1;
SET @errorInfo = '';

SELECT @inputValID = [inputValID]
FROM testTable
WHERE inputVal = @inputVal;

IF @inputValID IS NULL
BEGIN
SET @isError = 0;
SET @errorInfo = 'inputVal not found';
RETURN
END
END
```

I have used couple of C# methods to call the stored proc and I get they all return this error:

Procedure or function 'usp_StoredProcName' expects parameter '@inputVal', which was not supplied.

C# Method 1 (to call the stored proc)

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myFullConncectionStringToDB))
{
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_StoredProcName", con))
{
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputVal", "MyParamVal_12345");

  cmd.Parameters["@isError"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
  cmd.Parameters["@errorInfo"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

  con.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  var isError = cmd.Parameters["@isError"].Value;
  var errInfo = cmd.Parameters["@errorInfo"].Value;
  con.Close();
}
}
```

Method 2 ( to call the stored proc)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myFullConncectionStringToDB);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_StoredProcName", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter in_parm = new SqlParameter("@inputVal", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
in_parm.Size = 255;
in_parm.Value = "MyParamVal_12345";
in_parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters.Add(in_parm);

SqlParameter out_parm = new SqlParameter("@errorInfo", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
out_parm.Size = 255;
out_parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(out_parm);

SqlParameter out_parm1 = new SqlParameter("@isError", SqlDbType.Bit);
out_parm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(out_parm1);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Both of the above methods I tried return the same error:

```
Procedure or function 'usp_StoredProcName' expects parameter '@inputVal', which was not supplied.
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here in my C# code to execute the stored procedure.

I am clearly passing the parameter value in both of my methods but can't figure out why I keep getting this error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This just can't be the overall stack that's executing. The first example, which is perfect surrounding its usage of `using` and such, just wouldn't fail.

Comment: Is it possible the current version of your stored procedure is in one copy of the database, and the one C# is calling in another? This is a pretty common occurrence - let us know if your connection string has the attribute `AttachDbFileName` - and if it does, STOP using that horrible "feature." Please.

Comment: Thank you Aaron for your reply. Now how do you mean when you say... current version of the sp in one copy of the database and the one C# is calling in another. As far as I know, the c# is pointing to the correct stored procedure in the database.... so what else can go wrong here

Answer (score 0):

I usually break down the solution into pieces an make sure each one works.

First, test the Stored Procedure to make sure it works as planned.  Sample call is below.

```
-- Switch to your database
USE [YourDatabase]
GO

-- Declare output variables
DECLARE @out_is_error bit;
DECLARE @out_error_info nvarchar(255);

-- Execute sp
EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_StoredProcName] 
  N'In Data', 
  @isError = @out_is_error OUTPUT, 
  @errorInfo = @out_error_info OUTPUT;

-- Show any SQL errors / return data
PRINT @@ERROR;
PRINT 'Error = ' + @out_error_info;
PRINT 'Flag = ';
PRINT CAST(@out_is_error as CHAR(1));
GO
```

Next, look at the C# piece of the puzzle.  Aaron suggestion about correct database is a good one.  Do you have two copies of the SP floating around?

Good luck.